# X11: Почему XInput не работает в терминальном режиме?

Tags: linux, x11

Решил я проверить события клавиатуры через программу **xinput**. Проверял на трех компьютерах. На первых двух **xinput** работает нормально. Примерно так:

Список устройств:

```
$ xinput

⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)]
⎜  ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜  ↳ HID 1241:1177 id=8 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜  ↳ SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard id=10 [slave pointer (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
   ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Power Button id=6 [slave keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Power Button id=7 [slave keyboard (3)]
   ↳ SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard id=9 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

События устройства:

```
$ xinput test 9
key release 36
key press 48
key press 47
key release 48
key press 46
lkey release 47
key release 46
key press 41
key press 36
key release 41
key release 36
key press 62
key release 62
key press 37
```

А к третьему компьютеру у меня доступ через X-терминал. И на нем **xinput** не выполняет своей функции - не видит своих устройств и сегфолтится:

```
$ xinput
"pointer"   id=0    [XPointer]
"keyboard"  id=1    [XKeyboard]

$ xinput test 1
unable to find device '1'

$ xinput test-xi2 1
"keyboard"  id=1    [XKeyboard]
    Num_keys is 248
    Min_keycode is 8
    Max_keycode is 255
Ошибка сегментирования
```

**Вопрос**. XInput принципиально не работает через X-терминал? 
(В моем случае это x2go). 
Или это просто мне так свезло словить глюк, когда стандартная программа из комплекта x11 неработоспособна?

Окружение:
Откуда соединяюсь: Windows 7 Pro, клиент X2GO с официального сайта.
Куда соединяюсь: Debian 7.8, LXDE, терминальный сервер X2GO с официального сайта.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40970/discussion-on-question-by-xintrea-x11--xinput----).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

> Я соединяюсь по x2go с Винды на удаленный Линукс. xinput запускаю на удаленном Линуксе. И он там не работат, как написано в вопросе. А хотелось чтоб работал.

вы запускаете *x-сессию* на удалённой машине и средствами *x2go-сервера* к этой сессии подключаются устройства ввода: транслируемые *x2go-клиентом* интерфейсы к обслуживаемым *ms/windows* клавиатуре и мыши.

получается цепочка:

- клавиатура/мышь
- интерфейс к ним со стороны *ms/windows*
- ретрансляция этого интерфейса *x2go-клиентом* *x2go-серверу*
- ретрансляция этого интерфейса *x2go-сервером* *x-серверу*
- предоставление информации от *x-сервера* программе *xinput*

где-то в этой цепочке ретрансляций интерфейс существенно утрачивает свои функциональные возможности, упрощается и унифицируется.

где именно в описанной цепочке возникает приведённая вами ошибка, можно определить, вероятно, только средствами отладки (соответствующего компонента).

---

> Какова изначальная ваша задача?
>   Это очень долгая история: http://webhamster.ru/site/page/index/main/news/368
>   в интернет можно выходить только через терминальный сервер

если у вас есть возможность запустить *sshd* на машине, имеющей доступ в интернет, и «достучаться» до этого *sshd* с вашего локального компьютера, то, мне кажется, проще воспользоваться возможностями браузера (популярные браузеры умеют работать через *socks-proxy*) и *ssh-клиента* (который умеет предоставлять интерфейс *socks-proxy*). если вам нужны подробности по этому поводу, посмотрите ответ на этот вопрос: [как проксировать http[s] через ssh-туннель?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/178576)

Comment: > где-то в этой цепочке ретрансляций интерфейс существенно утрачивает свои функциональные возможности, упрощается и унифицируется.  -- 

Это все пространные рассуждения. Если клавиатура пробрасывается в X-сервер и работает нормально, то у нее должны нормально генерироваться события, иначе ничего бы не работало.

Comment: > запустить sshd на машине, имеющей доступ в интернет, и «достучаться» до этого sshd с вашего локального компьютера, то, мне кажется, проще воспользоваться возможностями браузера (популярные браузеры умеют работать через socks-proxy) и ssh-клиента (который умеет предоставлять интерфейс socks-proxy) -- 

Интернет блокируется локально на машине пользователя через Kaspersky. Он перехватывает даже DNS-траффик, и блокирует нелокальные домены. Прокси тут не поможет. Да это и не нужно. Есть требования информационной безопасности, их надо соблюдать. X-терминал делаю не только для себя.

Comment: @Xintrea, программа *xinput* всего лишь обращается к [одноимённому расширению](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xinput/tree/README) x-сервера. полная функциональность этой программы (и даже расширения), насколько я знаю, никак не обусловлена возможностями x-сервера **вообще работать** с устройствами ввода.

Comment: @Xintrea, в случае использования ssh для socks-проксирования весь трафик (включая и dns-запросы, при необходимости) проходит внутри ssh-туннеля, и, естественно, зашифрован. я кстати, сейчас пишу вопрос (и ответ) по поводу использования ssh как socks-proxy. как допишу — сразу сообщу вам.

Comment: @Xintrea, дописал: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/178576

Comment: To @alexanderbarakin : Спасибо, я возьму себе на заметку, т. к. надо понимать, что в требованиях по инф. безопасности написано только использование терминальных серверов. Совершенно неясно, как это убережет от утечки информации, но специалисты по инф. безопасности прочему-то думают что терминал - это панацея от утечек. Так сложилось в голове у "специалистов".