# Как проксировать http[s] через ssh-туннель?

Tags: linux, ssh, firefox, faq, ssh-tunnel

иногда возникает необходимость работать из браузера (например, *firefox*) как-будто бы из другой точки сети (куда есть доступ по протоколу *ssh*).

---

- например, нужно работать с веб-сайтом, который доступен только в локальной сети, из внешнего мира. при этом есть *ssh-доступ* к машине в этой локальной сети.
- или при доступе к веб-сайту требуется «прикинуться» работающим из другой страны (и есть *ssh-доступ* к серверу в этой стране).
- или в локальной сети вообще нет доступа в интернет, но есть *ssh-доступ* к машине, на которой соединения с интернетом разрешены.

как всё это осуществить? как настроить браузер? как запускать ssh-клиент?

Comment: к слову: пользоваться socks5 умеют многие программы. например, [клиент telegram](https://lifehacker.ru/kak-obojti-blokirovku-telegram/), [клиент skype](http://all-skype.ru/blog/skajp-cherez-proksi.html), тысячи их. // не проверял за неимением ни того ни другого, но, по идее, должны работать.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

предположим, что вы подключаетесь к некоему серверу по протоколу *ssh* такой командой:

```
$ ssh user@server
```

тогда вам потребуется:

1. запустить *ssh-клиент* с опцией `-D порт`, тогда программа *ssh* будет слушать указанный порт на локальном компьютере и (пока работает) все обращения к этому порту по протоколу [socks](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) будет ретранслировать на сервер:

   ```
   $ ssh -D 1122 user@server
   ```

   номер порта здесь произвольный, но, конечно, должен быть больше 1024 и меньше максимального номера порта (скорее всего, в вашей системе это 65536), и, конечно, не должен использоваться каким-нибудь другим локальным процессом.
2. в браузере *firefox* на странице `about:config` измените следующие параметры:

   1. `network.proxy.type = 1` (0 — отключить proxy)
   2. `network.proxy.socks = 127.0.0.1`
   3. `network.proxy.socks_port = 1122` (тот порт, что вы указали выше)
   4. `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns = true` (dns-запросы тоже будут отправляться через туннель)

   вышеперечисленные настройки можно сделать и с помощью «мышки» — на странице "preferences": "advanced" → "network" → "settings".

[image: socks settings for firefox]

для отключения проксирования достаточно поменять один параметр — `network.proxy.type = 0`.

вероятно, достаточно удобным будет завести новый профиль в *firefox* с этими настройками, чтобы они не мешали «обычной» работе. запустить *firefox*, чтобы он показал диалог выбора профилей, можно примерно так:

```
$ firefox --no-remote -P
```

можно и сразу запускать нужный профиль. например, если вы назвали профиль `proxy`:

```
$ firefox --no-remote -P proxy
```

---

скорее всего, подобные настройки можно осуществить и в других браузерах. обратитесь к документации вашего браузера по поводу использования *socks-proxy*.

Comment: А не подскажите, можно ли как-то это автоматизировать, т.е. не запускать каждый раз в терминале команду ssh -D 1122 user@server, вообще без запуска терминала? чтобы всегда по умолчанию был поднят этот тунель

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы

Comment: @tirael8 создать bash скрипт и ввести туда команды, скрипт поместить в любое удобное место, на рабочий стол например, также можно добавить в автозапуск системы, созданный вами bash скрипт