# Quagga: Анонсирование маршрутов из Python скрипта?

Tags: сеть, роутер, маршрутизация, mikrotik

**Что имеем:** Виртуальную машину с Quagga, одновременно являющуюся `tor gateway` с IP `192.168.1.253`, Mikrotik R951G-2HnD с IP `192.168.1.1`.

ВМ настроена так, что весь TCP трафик (кроме `22` и `179` портов) перенаправляется на `9040` порт, в TOR, который работает в режиме `Transparent Proxy`.

Таким образом, на Mikrotik можно можно вручную создать маршрут для любого IP адреса, и трафик пойдет в TOR. (вот пример для rutracker.org с IP-адресом `195.82.146.214`.

[image]

Также есть замечательное API, на выходе которого имеем огромную простыню из IP адресов, обновляется список каждый день: https://api.antizapret.info/group.php

**Внимание, вопрос (точнее, два):**

1) как настроить Quagga так, чтобы раз в день парсить список (наверное, силами скрипта на Python или на чём-то еще) и анонсировать через BGP все IP адреса из списка на `192.168.1.253` с тем, чтобы передать эти маршруты Mikrotik-у?

2) Если ответить на вопрос №1 представляется невозможным, то как из Python передать маршруты Quagga, чтобы тот анонсировал их Mikrotik?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что этот вопрос призывает к нарушению законодательства РФ.

Comment: @kff И что? РФ не центр мира. Да и укажите мне, где же это в законе запрещено обходить блокировки?

Comment: @Grigory E.: Вас интересует, где в законе запрещено обходить закон?

Comment: @Vlad мне совершенно не интересна юридическая сторона вопроса. Все эти обходы - лишь костыли... Временные, надеюсь.

Comment: То, что вам она не интересна, не означает, что вопрос автоматически хорош. Вы можете спросить, как при помощи программы украсть данные кредитки людей, которые по незнанию её установят на своём компьютере, это будет тоже вопрос вне рамок закона. Аргументируйте, чем ваш вопрос лучше.

Comment: @Vlad В интервью на РБК в начале 2016 года пресс-секретарь РКН Вадим Ампелонский заявил: "Обход блокировок не противоречит закону". Решение с тором пилю для себя, просто не устраивают меня всякие расширения для хромиков. VPN плохо отсутствием байпасса в случае ЧП, да и пинги увеличиваются и связанность страдает, да и с маршрутами для IPTV не хочу возиться.

Решение с динамической маршрутизацией выглядит самым нативным.

Comment: @GrigoryE.: Хм. А можно ссылку на интервью? (В идеале, разумеется, хотелось бы слово юриста, но с этим, понимаю, непросто.)

Comment: @Vlad https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpbYvCrSjXc

Comment: @GrigoryE.: Круто, спасибо.

Comment: Стоит убрать из вопроса нетехническую информацию - "нужно динамически обновлять маршруты, как это сделать" - это и есть суть вопроса. То, что вы пытаетесь сделать это ради обхода блокировки провайдера, который следует каким-то странным законам вашей страны - не имеет никакого отношения к технической стороне вопроса.

Comment: @Pasha, спасибо за критику, сейчас подправлю.

Comment: Мне кажется заголовок было бы тоже неплохо изменить

Comment: по-моему, образно выражаясь, вы хотите использовать межконтинентальную баллистическую ракету (с шахтой, инфраструктурой, системой «мёртвой руки») для стрельбы по воробьям. воспользуйтесь [каким-нибудь «ружьецом»](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/178576) — это и проще, и быстрее, и адекватнее задаче.

Comment: ну а если всё-таки очень нужна «мбр», то к python вопрос не имеет прямого отношения — освойте управление quagga из комндной строки и вызывайте то, что требуется, хоть из скрипта на брэйнфаке.

Comment: @ale Ружьецом не убить стаю воробьев... Роутер же не для одиноко стоящего ЭВМ, а минимум для 4 стационаров и кучи мобильных девайсов с зоопарком ОСей

Comment: @ale Ну то что надо! Где покопать про управление кагой? Какую литературу посоветуете? Этого-то я и жду в ответах...

Comment: я бы написал пассивный rip на питоне с нуля) протокол простой как пробка, микротик поймет.

Comment: Написать пассивный rip на питоне?)

Comment: Просматриваю старые вопросы по mikrotik... И решил прокомментировать. У soho микротиков не сильно много оперативной памяти, по этому такая массовая стрельба может намертво повесить маршрутизатор. Правда маршрутами динамическими я это не пробовал сделать, но вот пробовал блокировать трафик к вирусованным и опасным сайтам через Address list. 50к записей вешали железячку намертво. Они же для домашнего использования, по этому слабенькие