# Unix, GNU/Linux, перенаправления трафика для 80 порта

Tags: linux, nginx, unix, сеть, vpn

Есть локальный `home-server` c `ngix` но с динамическим `ip` и сервер с доменом но слабый `vpn-server` и необходимо получить доступ к сайту на сервере `home-server` и что-бы клиент подключался к `vpn-server` и желательно чтобы между этими северами было VPN тунель.

Пример:

```
Клиент -> vpn-server -> (VPN туннель) -> home-server -> Nginx
Клиент <- vpn-server <- (VPN туннель) <- home-server <- Nginx
```

Немного о серверах:

- vpn-server Ubuntu 16, OpenVPN
- home-server: Ubuntu 16, OpenVPN, Nginx

> На данный момент не знаю с чего начать.

Comment: изложите, пожалуйста, более чётко, что именно вызывает у вас затруднение. прямо в вопросе, разумеется.

Comment: возможно, вашей конечной целью является [вот это](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/178576)?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin немного не то, и немного не понимаю как это можно применить к моей проблеме

Comment: сейчас ваш вопрос чрезмерно глобален (я уж молчу, что про то, что он весьма туманен). предлагаю вам убрать из вопроса всё лишнее. как я понял, основная задача у вас — обращение к серверу, у которого иногда меняется адрес.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если VPN-сервер находится под вашим управлением, то

1) выдавайте home-серверу фиксированный адрес при VPN-подключении;

2) установите на VPN-сервер nginx в качестве фронт-энда (реверсного прокси) и задайте ему HOME-сервер в качестве апстрима:

```
upstream home-server {
    server <vpn-адрес home-server'а>
}
server {
    ...
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://home-server;
}
```

Другой вариант: можно не использовать nginx на VPN-сервере, а прописать на нем правило в DNAT:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <home-server-VPN-IP>
```

Для работоспособности этого варианта на home-сервере default route должен указывать на VPN-сервер.