# Как обойти блокировку docker'ом?

Tags: docker

Здравствуйте!

**Кратко о проблеме:**

В данный момент я нахожусь на территории Республики Крым, и как оказалось, docker блокирует pull образов из санкционного региона.

Вопрос в том, как обойти это ограничение?

Я пробовал пулить с поднятым впном, результат тот же, нулевой.

Единственный вариант, пришедший в голову - поднять докер на vps,скачать нужные образы, упаковать их в архив, и скачать на локальную машину, но очень уж вариант неудобный.

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь или совет!

Comment: Вам нужен туннель через какую-нибудь VPS в Германии или континентальной России. Незачем там что-то "поднимать" кроме собственно SSH.

Comment: У меня VPN тунель выходит в Норвегии. Но не работает. Или я вас неправильно понял

Comment: сравните вывод [команды](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30494038/4827341), сделанный на вашем компьютере, и на компьютере в норвегии (или куда у вас там выход в интернет проброшен). [или с этим выводом](http://paste.debian.net/899919/)

Comment: [socks proxy](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5989#issuecomment-205393601) плюс [socks proxy](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/178576)