# Как открыть проброшенный тунелем порт в интернет

Tags: ubuntu

Используя ubuntu сервер в качестве посредника, пробросил с windows порт 80 на его порт 3355, на ubuntu сервере используя команду

```
links2 127.0.0.1:3355
```

Сайт с Windows сервера(имеющего серый IP) пробрасывается и удачно показывается.
Пытаясь с внешней машины зайти по адресу(внешнему Ubuntu сервера) сайт не открывается.
Проброс осуществляется через тунель Putty(callback) по ssh.

Ещё раз попробую объяснить, видимо я очень неверно толкую..
На машине 1 поднят IIS, на ней запущено Putty и создан тунель к Ubuntu серверу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На ubuntu сервере, при обращении к 0.0.0.0:3325

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

На третьей машине из внешнего интернета:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Локалхост извне всегда недоступен. Попробуйте `*.*.*.*` или IP машины (той сетевой с которой будет дан доступ).

Comment: Пробую с внешки адрес уже ubuntu сервера. 94.тд тп.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` - это локалхост, он извне всегда не доступен. Запишите туда другой адрес.

Comment: я писал выше что использую внешний адрес, когда пытаюсь зайти из интернета НЕ 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Для проброса поменяй `127.0.0.1` на `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Добавил картинки, что я пытаюсь сделать, видимо мое красноречие не помогает :( Посмотрите, пожалуйста, кто уже  старался помочь, может станет понятнее.

Comment: возможно, будет полезно: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/178576