# При подключении через pptp трафик проходит через локального провайдера

Tags: linux, сеть, vps, vpn

Столкнулся с весьма странной проблемой. Постараюсь описать по порядку:
Имеется VPS в Hetzner, на нём поднят VPN через pptpd и свой кеширующий DNS.
При подключении через VPN все публичные сервисы видят мой локальный ПК как находящийся в Германии.
Но при доступе к заблокированным сайтам каким-то образом выводится заглушка от провайдера (Interzet дом.ру СПб).

Ниже прилагаю трассировку до первого попавшегося адреса из реестра и до google.com

Трассировка до случайного адреса из реестра с локального ПК:

```
tobishua@tobishua-laptop:~$ traceroute www.jw.org
traceroute to www.jw.org (92.255.241.100), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  44.846 ms * *
 2  172.31.1.1 (172.31.1.1)  45.192 ms * *
 3  cnode19.12.cpool.your-server.de (136.243.181.148)  46.047 ms * *
 4  static.129.181.243.136.clients.your-server.de (136.243.181.129)  47.219 ms  47.207 ms  49.014 ms
 5  core23.fsn1.hetzner.com (213.239.229.17)  49.007 ms core24.fsn1.hetzner.com (213.239.229.21)  48.995 ms core23.fsn1.hetzner.com (213.239.229.17)  48.984 ms
 6  core4.fra.hetzner.com (213.239.229.73)  53.044 ms  49.303 ms core1.fra.hetzner.com (213.239.203.153)  49.404 ms
 7  juniper4.pop2.fra.hetzner.com (213.239.245.1)  49.386 ms juniper4.pop2.fra.hetzner.com (213.239.245.10)  54.334 ms juniper4.pop2.fra.hetzner.com (213.239.245.1)  49.345 ms
 8  ae6-229.RT.IRX.FKT.DE.retn.net (87.245.245.113)  50.328 ms  50.290 ms  50.277 ms
 9  ae13-1.RT.M9.MSK.RU.retn.net (87.245.233.22)  87.732 ms  87.722 ms  86.113 ms
10  GW-ERTelecom.retn.net (87.245.229.82)  88.301 ms  88.265 ms  88.247 ms
11  lag-2-435.bgw01.nn.ertelecom.ru (91.144.185.82)  95.042 ms  95.021 ms  95.001 ms
12  lag-100-435.bsr01.nn.ertelecom.ru (91.144.185.81)  3918.150 ms * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Трассировка непосредственно с VPS:

```
root@srv-02 ~ # traceroute www.jw.org
traceroute to www.jw.org (23.74.189.137), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.31.1.1 (172.31.1.1)  0.101 ms * *
 2  cnode19.12.cpool.your-server.de (136.243.181.148)  0.586 ms * *
 3  static.129.181.243.136.clients.your-server.de (136.243.181.129)  0.502 ms  0.491 ms  0.475 ms
 4  core24.fsn1.hetzner.com (213.239.229.21)  0.581 ms core23.fsn1.hetzner.com (213.239.229.17)  0.536 ms core24.fsn1.hetzner.com (213.239.229.21)  0.365 ms
 5  core1.fra.hetzner.com (213.239.203.153)  5.024 ms core1.fra.hetzner.com (213.239.229.77)  4.987 ms core1.fra.hetzner.com (213.239.203.153)  5.003 ms
 6  ecix-fra2.netarch.akamai.com (62.69.146.12)  4.993 ms  4.908 ms  4.874 ms
 7  a23-74-189-137.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.74.189.137)  4.902 ms  4.893 ms  4.878 ms
```

Трассировка до google.com с локального ПК:

```
tobishua@tobishua-laptop:~$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (172.217.22.174), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  45.183 ms * *
 2  172.31.1.1 (172.31.1.1)  45.102 ms * *
 3  cnode19.12.cpool.your-server.de (136.243.181.148)  47.901 ms * *
 4  static.129.181.243.136.clients.your-server.de (136.243.181.129)  47.862 ms  47.854 ms  47.855 ms
 5  core24.fsn1.hetzner.com (213.239.229.21)  47.828 ms  47.819 ms  47.816 ms
 6  core1.fra.hetzner.com (213.239.203.153)  61.271 ms  64.844 ms  64.809 ms
 7  juniper1.pop1.fra.hetzner.com (213.239.203.238)  57.043 ms juniper1.pop1.fra.hetzner.com (213.239.245.5)  57.028 ms core2.ams.hetzner.com (213.239.203.158)  62.164 ms
 8  hetzner-gw.google.com (213.133.126.250)  62.153 ms 72.14.211.228 (72.14.211.228)  59.307 ms  59.311 ms
 9  216.239.43.242 (216.239.43.242)  59.284 ms  59.270 ms 216.239.46.180 (216.239.46.180)  52.807 ms
10  216.239.47.100 (216.239.47.100)  58.420 ms 209.85.243.131 (209.85.243.131)  50.437 ms 216.239.57.194 (216.239.57.194)  50.358 ms
11  108.170.238.60 (108.170.238.60)  59.353 ms  59.666 ms  59.974 ms
12  209.85.244.141 (209.85.244.141)  63.379 ms  62.926 ms  63.269 ms
13  209.85.241.195 (209.85.241.195)  85.004 ms 209.85.249.56 (209.85.249.56)  96.798 ms  96.768 ms
14  209.85.254.32 (209.85.254.32)  81.244 ms  80.295 ms 209.85.254.12 (209.85.254.12)  79.969 ms
15  108.170.235.65 (108.170.235.65)  81.716 ms  81.122 ms  81.457 ms
16  arn09s11-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.22.174)  81.096 ms  81.607 ms  81.358 ms
```

Трассировка до google.com с VPS:

```
root@srv-02 ~ # traceroute www.jw.org
traceroute to www.jw.org (23.74.189.137), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.31.1.1 (172.31.1.1)  0.101 ms * *
 2  cnode19.12.cpool.your-server.de (136.243.181.148)  0.586 ms * *
 3  static.129.181.243.136.clients.your-server.de (136.243.181.129)  0.502 ms  0.491 ms  0.475 ms
 4  core24.fsn1.hetzner.com (213.239.229.21)  0.581 ms core23.fsn1.hetzner.com (213.239.229.17)  0.536 ms core24.fsn1.hetzner.com (213.239.229.21)  0.365 ms
 5  core1.fra.hetzner.com (213.239.203.153)  5.024 ms core1.fra.hetzner.com (213.239.229.77)  4.987 ms core1.fra.hetzner.com (213.239.203.153)  5.003 ms
 6  ecix-fra2.netarch.akamai.com (62.69.146.12)  4.993 ms  4.908 ms  4.874 ms
 7  a23-74-189-137.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (23.74.189.137)  4.902 ms  4.893 ms  4.878 ms
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь в этой странной ситуации.

Comment: Я бы для начала попробовал сделать тунель через ssh (у Вас похоже и там и там linux или что то подобное). На домашней машине запускаете `ssh -D 8080 <vps-server>` и вводите пароль по необходимости. В браузере (для фаерфокса это точно работает, лучше на нем испытать, в настройках сети актвируем socks5 прокси и вбиваем 127.0.0.1:8080 (этот порт задан выше) А также в настройках меняем `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns` на true. В России это не проверялось, но проверялось в других странах, которые блокируют направо и налево и все работает.

Comment: @KoVadim, [на будущее](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/178576)

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался.
Провайдер подменяет DNS-запросы, поэтому и получается такое неприятное поведение.