# Создание прокси на удаленном компьютере - C++

Tags: ssh, proxy, tcp, nat, socks5

Есть такая у меня ситуация: имеется 2 компьютера, один я хочу использовать как прокси-сервер, внешнего айпи нет, поэтому нашел какую то инфу что можно сделать бэкконект через свой сервер. И через этот прокси можно уже в интернет заходить через этот прокси. Алгоритм там такой что порты задаются на самом сервере. не представляю как это реализовано, знаю что через netcat. Надо же ещё программную оболочку сделать наверное. Не подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/178576

Comment: Тут же получается вид localhost:port
А ведь из инетрнета не достучаться так. Из интернета-то надо подключаться 0.0.0.0:0000

Comment: Мы переходим через ip сервера, а надо через ip машины пользователя из сервера.