# Как настроить проброс портов для HTTP трафика на proxy?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, ssh, proxy, iptables

Поднимаю SSH туннель

```
sudo ssh -f -C2qTnN -D 1080 root@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Далее, хочу чтобы весь веб-трафик (:80) шел через этот тунель.
Это можно сделать через настройки браузера (SOCKS 5), но я хочу сделать это через IPTABLES.

Нашел код, делаю так:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1080
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1080
```

Но трафик не идет через SSH прокси все равно.

Помогите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? У меня Ubuntu 16

Comment: используя опцию `-D порт`, вы не создаёте туннель типа ppp (чего, как я подозреваю, вы пытаетесь добиться), а указываете программе *ssh* выступать в роли socks-сервера и слушать на указанном порту обращения по [протоколу socks](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS). клиент должен [обращаться к вашей программе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/178576) именно по этому протоколу.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Да, вы верно всё говорите; Подскажите, как все это дело реализовать, чтобы работало через iptables?

Comment: задайте **новый** вопрос с изложением того, **чего же вам, собственно, надо**. в этом вопросе можно лишь догадываться, что же именно вы хотите **реализовать**. p.s. если я правильно настроил сегодня с утра свой миелофон, то он мне подсказыват, что вы хотиет получить то, что физически нереализуемо. поройтесь в вопросах здесь на сайте - подобные "хотелки" время от времени посещают "буйные головы".

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Возможно я не правильно выразился. Нужно трафик программы (допустим Zoiper) отправлять через прокси; В этой программе нет прокси. Поэтому хотел узнать, возможно ли это сделать через iptables; Также знаю, что можно сделать это через VPN, но VPN у нас блокируют. Поэтому, как быть?

Comment: стало чуть понятнее.1. *vpn у нас блокируют* - исходя из значения термина *vpn* (virtual private network) это в принципе невозможно, ведь "весь интернет" (с точки зрения клиента, находящегося за маршрутизатором) - это частный случай "виртуальной частной сети". 2. вероятно, вам всё-таки надо воспользоваться как раз vpn-ом. например, [ppp over ssh](https://www.google.ru/search?q=ppp+over+ssh)

Comment: если для одной программы хотите обращение через socks5 прокси, которое она не поддерживает, настроить, то попробуйте proxychains

Answer (score 2):

для решения неозвученной стоящей перед вами задачи вы выбрали неподходящий инструмент.

программа *ssh*, будучи вызвана с опцией `-D порт`, начинает слушать на указанном порту обращения по [протоколу socks](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) (версий 4 и 5), выступая в роли *socks-сервера*.

и ваш клиент должен выступать в роли *socks-клиента*, т.е. обращаться к программе *ssh* именно по этому протоколу.

многие современные браузеры умеют работать в роли *socks-клиента*. например, *firefox*: [Как проксировать http[s] через ssh-туннель?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/178576)

> Нужно трафик программы (допустим Zoiper) отправлять через прокси; в этой программе нет прокси

вероятно, вам надо организовать *vpn* (virtual private network) поверх протокола *ssh*. например, [ppp over ssh](https://www.google.ru/search?q=ppp+over+ssh), и затем "заворачивать" трафик этой программы внутрь созданного [ppp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PPP_(%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB))-туннеля.