# Как настроить свой VPN для обхода блокировок?

Tags: linux, безопасность, vpn, vps, блокировки

- способ должен работать на любом VPS без привязки к какому либо конкретному сервису;
- желательно использование только бесплатного ПО. Linux VPS;
- безопасность;
- желательно минимум усилий.

Comment: 1. Ставите докер 2. ставите любой понравившийся докер контейнер, например этот https://hub.docker.com/r/hwdsl2/ipsec-vpn-server/ Проще вряд ли придумать

Comment: @TotalPusher Разве это безопасно пользоваться сборкой от некого  Лина Сонга? Всё таки весь мой трафик будет проходить через этот VPN сервер.

Comment: просто не пользуйтесь этим сервисом (все и так прекрасно понимают, куда Вы хотите попасть).

Comment: @KoVadim Нет, я не про Телеграм спрашиваю. Меня интересуют Cloudflare, AWS и GCP. В любом случае конкретные цели использования VPN к вопросу не относятся. Цель одна: обходить блокировки. А свой VPN потому что дешевле, меньше вероятность блокировки, в случае чего можно быстро переехать, и теоретически безопаснее бесплатных VPN.

Comment: А вам обязательно именно VPN? С обычным SOCKS5-прокси возни намного меньше, например

Answer (score 4):

да ничего не надо ставить. *sshd* на сервере уж точно есть. а *pppd* на «дружелюбных» системах обычно присутствует (но даже если вдруг отсутствует, то поставить соответствующий пакет вовсе несложно, правда?)

дальше берём первую попавшуюся инструкцию про [*ppp-over-ssh*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VPN_over_SSH#Using_PPP_over_SSH) и выполняем (на клиентской стороне) супер-секретную-скрываемую-агентами-кейджиби-и-сиайэй длинную такую команду:

```
$ sudo pppd updetach noauth silent nodeflate 10.20.20.2:10.20.20.1 pty "ssh root@сервер pppd nodetach notty noauth"
```

и если всё в порядке, получаем в ответ:

```
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/18
BSD-Compress (15) compression enabled
local  IP address 10.20.20.2
remote IP address 10.20.20.1
```

всё, ***vpn*** (***виртуальная частная сеть***) у вас работает. дальше уже «заворачивайте» нужный трафик внутрь созданного только что туннеля:

```
$ ip a sh dev ppp0
26: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 3
    link/ppp 
    inet 10.20.20.2 peer 10.20.20.1/32 scope global ppp0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

p.s. ну, естественно, ваш локальный пользователь `root` должен уметь без пароля подключаться по протоколу *ssh* как `root@сервер`.

p.p.s. да и вообще в подавляющем большинстве случаев и vpn-то не требуется: [Как проксировать http[s] через ssh-туннель?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/178576)

Comment: http(s) через ssh-туннель по протоколу socks5 это очень интересное решение!