# Необходимо установить MonoDevelop и Mono-Complete НО

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

РКН блокирует ip 152.199.20.1 в котором находится все, что нужно для установки пакетов Mono и  MonoDevelop. Отсюда вытекает вопрос, есть ли альтернативный метод установки или может ли кто-нибудь подсказать, как скрыться за прокси и установить Mono и MonoDevelop через терминал?
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: На время установки включить VPN туннель.

Comment: @dimka3210 А как это сделать?

Comment: Купить доступ. Например cloudvpn pro. Они присылают файл настроек и инструкцию. Подключается потом в одну строку в консоли.

Comment: @ dimka3210 А бесплатного варианта нет?

Comment: 1. так оно «через терминал» [и устанавливается](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/#fndtn-download-lin). 2. если есть ssh-доступ к серверу, с которого ip-адрес доступен, то воспользуйтесь [`ssh -D`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/533543/178576) + `tsocks`. 3. и вообще можно и debian-овскими репозиториями воспользоваться. не так свежо, зато явно доступно.

Comment: vpn — слишком жирный вариант для такой мелкой задачи.... если вся установка производится средствами apt, то достаточно любой прокси — хоть тот же пресловутый tor поднять...

Answer (score 0):

Скачайте и установите с официального сайта http://www.monodevelop.com/download/

Сегодня этот сайт доступен совершенно свободно.