# Пропадает интернет после подключения через ovpn

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, amazon-web-services

Был у меня сервер на амазоне(там всё работало и работает), да ркн заблочил его, пришлось сделать образ и создать на основе его новый инстанс. Казалось бы, что может пойти не так. Всё запустил, на всякий случай сверился с https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openvpn-ubuntu-16-04-ru подключаюсь без каких-либо ошибок к ovpn, и интернет пропадает. В security group даже ради интереса разрешил весь трафик, но это не помогло. Точнее будет сказать сайты пингуются, а вот в браузере ничего не открывается
лог https://pastebin.com/UUCjnr0g

Честно говоря я даже не понимаю где искать причину такого поведения.

Comment: 2018 год, а люди всё ещё ручками всё настраивают. Возьмите готовый скрипт и не мучайтесь https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install

Comment: Весь интерес и состоит в том, чтобы ручками настраивать

Comment: Настроил скриптом и всё равно ничего не поменялось

Comment: чего только люди не понапридумывают, чтоб только не пользоваться [простыми доступными инструментами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/178576)…

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, зачем мне прокси если нужен впн? Мне не только http(+s) надо

Comment: Попробовал запустить даже новый инстанс, настроить всё скриптом, я ж скрипт кидди, но ни по udp ни по tcp так интернет и не появился