# Не работает curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash

Tags: linux, bash, curl, elementary-os

Хочу установить `sdkman` на `elementary OS Loki`.
Пытаюсь делать всё по инструкции с [сайта](https://sdkman.io/install), ввожу в консоли `curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash` и ничего не происходит. Разработчики sdkman сказали, что возможно это из-за блокировок серверов, но у меня стоит vpn и я могу пинговать `get.sdkman.io`, а также если я ввожу этот адрес в браузер то у меня открывается их страница, отсюда я сделал вывод, что дело не в блокировке, в чём тогда может быть проблема?

UPD:
попробовал изменить запрос вот результат

```
curl -sv "https://get.sdkman.io/" | bash
Rebuilt URL to: https://get.sdkman.io/
Trying 159.89.187.78...
Connected to get.sdkman.io (159.89.187.78) port 443 (#0)
found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
found 597 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
ALPN, offering http/1.1
gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the push function.
Closing connection 0
```

UPD2:

```
ls -l $(which bash)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1037528 ноя 27  2017 /bin/bash

bash --version
GNU bash, версия 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

UPD3:

```
$ wget 'https://get.sdkman.io'
--2018-09-27 16:25:07--  https://get.sdkman.io/
Распознаётся get.sdkman.io (get.sdkman.io)... 159.89.187.78
Подключение к get.sdkman.io (get.sdkman.io)|159.89.187.78|:443... 
соединение установлено.
Не удаётся установить SSL-соединение.
```

UPD4:
Я использую VPN, на сайт get.sdkman.io через браузер я зайти могу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А покажите, пожалуйста, результат команд: `ls -l $(which bash)` и `bash --version`.

Comment: Боюсь тут я не смогу помочь, попробуй поискать в инете, что такое: `gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the push function`.

Comment: спасибо за направление)

Comment: Да недоступен просто `get.sdkman.io` от Вас (от меня, кстати, тоже). Воспользуйтесь любой публичной прокси или анонимайзером. Ну или вот, дарю: https://pastebin.com/gj1ARyjp (P.S. Заблокирован позорнадзором по статьям 15.3 15.4)

Comment: @nobody, у меня открывается браузером страница get.sdkman.io и там всё то-же самое, что вы скинули ссылкой.

Comment: В браузере можете отырть страницу? get.sdkman.io или  https://get.sdkman.io у меня скрипт выдает. Смотрите блокирвоку по IP или другие фильтры. Ваша локальный bash/curl тут не причем.

Comment: Если очень нужно скинул на гист https://gist.github.com/Hellseher/2f003fb54063bda68d05083c3b4e0961

Comment: *openssl* недавно обновляли?

Comment: @0andriy, я eOS неделю назад установил) openssl не обновлял

Comment: @Hellseher, get.sdkman.io открываю в браузере и вижу текст скрипта,  копирую этот скрипт в .sh файл, скрипт запускается и падает gnutls_handshake(35) failed

Comment: @AndreyPopov, исправьте или добавьте такую строчку в */etc/ssl/openssl.cnf*: `MinProtocol = TLSv1`.

Comment: @0andriy, не помогло...

Comment: там из всего скрипок только одна строчка что-то качает из сети попробуйте другие способы получить архив и закоментируйте ее: `echo "Download script archive..."`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

согласно информации с сайта `https://zapret.info/index.php?url=get.sdkman.io`:

> Сожалеем, ресурс get.sdkman.io (159.89.187.78) находится в списке заблокированных ресурсов на территории Российской Федерации!

---

если у вас имеется *ssh*-доступ к серверу, на котором сайт `get.sdkman.io` (и `api.sdkman.io`, к которому происходят обращения уже внутри скрипта, который вы хотите получить и выполнить) **не заблокирован**, то можете воспользоваться советом из другого моего ответа: [Как проксировать http[s] через ssh-туннель?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/178576) (точнее, первым пунктом из ответа).

1. в отдельном эмуляторе терминала запускаете проксирующий процесс:

   ```
   $ ssh -D 1122 user@server
   ```
2. в другом эмуляторе терминала, где собираетесь запускать программу *curl*, объявляете переменную окружения `HTTPS_PROXY`, значение которой использует программа:

   ```
   $ export HTTPS_PROXY=socks5://localhost:1122
   ```

   (номер порта — тот же самый, что вы указывали и при запуске *ssh*)
3. теперь в этом эмуляторе терминала команда

   ```
   $ curl https://get.sdkman.io | ...
   ```

   благополучно отработает.

---

если вы, как и я, не доверяете всяким левым сайтам и устанавливаете программы с них исключительно в docker-контейнерах, то контейнер надо запускать (хотя бы на стадии запуска скриптов с `sdkman.io`), например, с опцией `--network=host`. первый пункт выполняете на хост-машине, второй и третий — внутри контейнера.

Answer (score -4):

Просто используй

```
curl -s "http://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

Comment: нет, не работает такой способ

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/293804)

Comment: @Air иногда автоматическая проверка ошибается:)

Comment: Вы бы почитали UPD3 в вопросе. А лучше удалите ответ, он тут не о том.