# Безопасный удаленный доступ к ЭВМ с Ubuntu из любой точки мира

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, remote-access

Дано: ноутбук с ОС Ubuntu, ПК на работа.

Требуется: подключиться к ноутбуку с работы в графическом режиме.

Требования: строго ограничить действия пользователя, например, предоставить доступ только к браузеру и не более!

**Скажите, пожалуйста, как это лучше всего сделать?**

P.S.: ПК и ноутбук не в одной локальной сети :-D

Comment: Вы бы хоть расписали у вас ип статический для начала на ноутбуке?  Ноутбук за natом? Вводные данные нулевые как по мне.

Comment: Поставьте team viewer проще всего.

Comment: Удалённое подключение и ограничение действий пользователя — это две раздельные никак не связанные задачи. Сперва создать ограниченное окружение, а уже потом в этом окружении настраивать доступ по удалёнке

Comment: Вам прям точно необходимо "в графическом режиме"? Возможно, исходя из описанного, возможности удалённо запустить браузер будет достаточно?

Comment: гонять картинки по сети — бессмысленная нервотрёпка (от gui всё-таки ожидается хоть какая-то интерактивность). надстраивать поверх этого ещё один тормоз в виде виртуальной частной сети — вообще сплошное издевательство над людьми. очень похоже, что нужно вам [совсем другое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/178576), просто вы, будучи измученными операционной системой ms/windows, даже не знаете, что «и так можно».

Comment: Один вопрос - Зачем?

Comment: @НиколайГабараев, на этом можно зарабатывать.