# Ubuntu 16.04 маршрутизировать весь трафик через OpenVPN с помощью Network Manager

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, network-manager

На чистую ubuntu 18.04 server (amazon EC2) я установил openvpn access server 2.8.3 с помощью следующих команд взятых из официальной документации:

```
1) apt update && apt -y install ca-certificates wget net-tools gnupg
2) wget -qO - https://as-repository.openvpn.net/as-repo-public.gpg | apt-key add -
3)echo "deb http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian bionic main">/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list
4) apt update && apt -y install openvpn-as
```

Далее я зашел на веб морду openvpn сервера https://xxx:943 и скачал конфигурационный файл client.ovpn.

Содержимое client.ovpn:

```
    client
    cipher AES-256-CBC
    setenv FORWARD_COMPATIBLE 1
    server-poll-timeout 4
    nobind
    remote xxx 1194 udp
    remote xxx 1194 udp
    remote xxx 443 tcp
    remote xxx 1194 udp
    remote xxx 1194 udp
    remote xxx 1194 udp
    remote xxx 1194 udp
    remote xxx 1194 udp
    dev tun
    dev-type tun
    ns-cert-type server
    setenv opt tls-version-min 1.0 or-highest
    #reneg-sec 604800
    sndbuf 0
    rcvbuf 0
    auth-user-pass
    comp-lzo no
    verb 3
    setenv PUSH_PEER_INFO
```

Я работаю на ubuntu 16.04 desktop, где я установил network-manager-openvpn-gnome.
Далее в нём я сделал импорт client.ovpn. После чего я пытаюсь подключаться к openvpn в network manager..[image]

Подключение происходит успешно, внутренняя впн сеть работает, но у меня перестаёт работать интернет. Интернет трафик не хочет работать через VPN. Мне нужно чтобы мой весь интернет трафик начал работать через vpn сервер.
В настройках сервера стоит отметка, что интернет-трафик клиента должен маршрутизироваться через VPN, но почему-то этого не происходит..[image]

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема? 
Если подключаться через terminal (sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn), тогда весь интернет-трафик маршрутизируется через openvpn сервер, как и нужно. Если подключаться через openvpn client на windows 7, так же всё работает отлично. Но не на ubuntu в network managere.
Но мне нужно это настроить в network-managere.

Comment: с наибольшей вероятностью — недостаточно высок приоритет у нужного вам маршрута. см. `$ ip r` — чем меньше значение метрики у маршрута, тем выше его приоритет. хотя нет. с ещё большей вероятностью пакеты «глохнут» на сервере.

Comment: почему тогда через терминал sudo openvpn client.ovpn работает, и на windown 7 через openvpn client так же работает? Тогда по идее так же пакеты должны глохнуть

Comment: *почему тогда через терминал работает?* — ну, раз работает, так пользуйтесь. будет желание — отправьте сообщение об ошибке разработчикам той граф.поделки, в которой вы мышкой пытаетесь настраивать. а вообще: понятно, что тема «если вам нужен доступ к какой-то сети, то впн — единстванная возможность» активно спонсируется продавцами услуг «впн-серверов». но ведь подавляющему большинству надо всего лишь «открывать веб-странички». а это доступно [прямо из коробки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/178576).

Comment: будете сообщение об ошибке (о котором я упомянул выше) писать — приложите вывод `$ ip r` в обоих случаях и ткните разработчиков носом в различие метрик.

Comment: а я вручную могу у себя что-то поменять, чтобы оно заработало?

Comment: изменить метрику существующего маршрута? с помощью `ip route change`, насколько помню, нельзя. можно удалить маршрут и создать заново с нужной метрикой. например, вот так `$ ip r` показывает нужный маршрут: `169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000`. удаляете: `$ sudo ip r d 169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000`, затем добавляете: `$ sudo ip r a 169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 2000`. здесь `r` — сокращение от `route`, `d` — `del`, `a` — `add`. см. `$ man ip-route`

Comment: кстати, если вам не только веб-страницы надо, но и ещё какой-нибудь трафик, посмотрите на [настройки клиента](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533542/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-https-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-ssh-%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c#comment1905607_533542). вполне возможно, что там есть и про «socks5 proxy». тогда вам и не нужно громоздить все вот эти сложности: всё будет работать «из коробки».

Comment: спасибо, как раз то что нужно. А не подскажите, можно ли как-то это автоматизировать, т.е. не запускать каждый раз в терминале команду ssh -D 1122 user@server, вообще без запуска терминала? чтобы всегда по умолчанию был поднят этот тунель