# Не работают soks5 proxy. ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, proxy, socks5, puppeteer

Через puppeteer пишу парсер.
Вот конфигурация chrome (в интернете везде этот пример):

```
  '--proxy-server=socks5://proxyHost:proxyPort',
  '--host-resolver-rules="MAP * ~NOTFOUND , EXCLUDE proxyHost"',
```

В итоге браузер выкидывает ошибку:

```
ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

Также устанавливал эти прокси в настройках Ubuntu. Сеть/Сетевой прокси. И такая же ошибка.

Куда копать? Что не так?

Comment: для начала проверьте доступен ли этот порт: `$ telnet proxyHost proxyPort`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, $ telnet 194.38.9.66 65234
Trying 194.38.9.66...
Connected to 194.38.9.66.
Escape character is '^]'.
[Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, на по идее есть авторизация. Когда использую эту же проксю на другом порту для http/https , то выпадает диалоговое окно для авторизации, а с socks5 такого нет

Comment: если порт доступен, проверьте собственно функциональность сервера: `$ curl --socks5 proxyHost:proxyPort https://ipinfo.io/ip`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, curl: (7) Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0. (2)

Comment: ни разу не пользовался socks5 с аутентификацией (и абсолютно негде проверить), потому не могу подсказать: это просто неработающий socks5-сервер или это он так эзотерически требует аутентификацию. ну, попробуйте передать ему логин+пароль. как обычно для url: `$ curl -x socks5://логин:пароль@proxyHost:proxyPort https://ipinfo.io/ip`

Comment: Нет, так не получается(

Comment: значит, остаётся одно: неработающий socks5-сервер. ну так вы сами запустите [socks5-сервер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/533543/178576): `$ ssh -D порт пользователь@хост` и на нём уж и тренируйте свой http-клиент.