# Подключения к удалённому компьютеру

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, teamviewer

Есть компьютер за 300 км от меня, к которому мне необходимо подключится. Желательно с графическим интерфейсом,  но можно и по ssh. На удалённом компьютере стоит убунту 16, сильно урезанная с xfce. На нем так же стоит тимвивер 9. Именно 9. У меня ubuntu 20. Поставить тимвивер 9 мне не удаётся, проблема с кучей зависимостей которые я никак немогу устранить. Да и в гугле пишут что стоит забить, и использовать версию новое.пробывал запустить тимвивер через виртуальную машину (virtual box). Установил семёрку, поставил тимвивер, но не подключается, пишет просто "не удалось подключиься". По ssh не могу подключится так как не знаю как правильно подключиться. Там есть идет таким оброзом: сначала интернет приходит в роутер тплинк, от тплинка по кабелю идет роутер asus с прошивкой OpenWRT. На нем есть ssh и если не ошибаюсь, он на 22 порту. И только от роутера асус по кабелю со статически айпи идет кабель на нужный мне компьютер. На том конце есть человек, который далек от компьютеров, но может выполнять не сложные инструкции. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как то подключится к компьютеру не используя тимвивер и ссш? Там тимвивер обновлять нельзя. Так же пробывал ставить тимвивер через playonlinux. Через раз запускается но не подключается с той же ошибкой как и на виртуальной машине. Или у меня 2 варианта: ехать туда и ставить винду? Подскажите, есть ли аналогичное решение?

Comment: Удалённо очень много роутеров. Проще издалека чтобы сделали туннель к вам. Если бы у вас был белый IP, то можно было бы сделать.

Comment: см. как делать туннель https://habr.com/ru/post/81607/

Comment: @AlexGlabe вот и я о том. Вся сложность что идет несколько роутеров. Я просто не могу понять как правильно писать команду. Допустим у меня первый роутер с айпи 10.20:50 второй роутер 192.168:65432 и сам компьютер 192.111:22 . С первого роутера я попрошу порт 50 на второй роутер. Со второго роутера порт 65432 я попрошу на компьютер. Ну и на компьютере порт 22 используется. Как команда будет выглядеть.  Я уже понял, что просто так не выйдет

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/191416

Comment: ssh ...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два простых* варианта:

1. донастроить виртуальную машину с TV, чтобы она могла ходить в интернет (возможно, сейчас проблемы с подключением из неё именно из-за отсутствия интернета).
2. поднять где-нибудь виртуальный сервер с белым адресом (хоть на хетцнере, хоть на амазоне - везде, где есть почасовка). Затем сделать то, что сказал @eri: с удалённой машины зайти на этот сервер с пробросом порта:
   `ssh -C -R 2201:127.0.0.1:22 ip.addr.of.server`
   затем зайти с вашей машины на этот же сервер: `ssh -C ip.addr.of.server`
   затем с сервера приконнектиться к проброшенному порту: `ssh -p 2201 localhost` - и вы окажетесь на удалённой машине.

NB: если ваша машина и так доступна через интернет, то второе решение сводится к описанному @eri.

* сложные варианты типа нахождения модемов для телефонной линии и настройки mgetty на удалённой машине рассматривать не будем.

Comment: Ваш ответ мне очень помог. Но есть пару вопрос. Можно какую нибудь сылку про подробное обьеснение как это работает. Что это за ключи. гугл на такие вопросы отвечает быстро, готовым примером, как и у вас, но мне бы хотелось понять что это и как оно работает. И еще вопрос. У меня таких сложных 2 компьютера, у меня сразу появилась мысля написать простой скрипт который при включение компьютера сразу бы конектилса к серверу, а я при необходимости мог просто заходить на эти машины. Если я правильно понял, то первый компьютер прописать как 127.0.0.1 а второй 127.0.0.2, но я в этом сомневаюсь

Comment: в запущенных случаях работает самый простой метод - отправка ящика с машиной доставки)

Comment: @Максим лучше всего объяснит man ssh в части про -R и -L. Они пробрасывают порты соответственно на удалённой и локальной машине. "Удалённая"/"локальная" здесь — по отношению к машине, на которой запускается ssh с соответствующим ключом. Разделять надо не по адресу, а по порту, то есть с первой машины форвардим порт 2201, а с другой — 2202. Скрипт писать не надо, всё уже написано до нас: https://habr.com/ru/post/81607/

Answer (score 3):

tmate - програмка которая подключает ссх через сервер.

Идешь на https://tmate.io/ и качаешь static build. Отправляешь на объект. Там нужно выставить права на исполнение и запустить. На терминале будет ссылка по которой можно зайти в консоль той машины. Там попытаться обновить тимвьювер или поставить anydesk.

Если не удастся, то настраиваешь свой роутер на проброс ссх. На удаленном запускаешь vnc. Командой на удаленном компе

```
ssh -R 5901:127.1:5900 user@home.ip
```

прокидываешь порт с их локалхоста на свой. Через програмку "Просмотр удаленных рабочих столов" подключайся на 127.0.0.1:5901 и попадешь на удаленный компьютер

С пробросом можно обойтись вмето tmate.

ssh -R 2200:127.1:22 ... - подключаешься по ссх оттуда к себе с параметром R. Пробросит порт по которому ты уже подключишься туда и настроишь autossh

Comment: Немного не понял

Comment: добавил подробностей

Comment: ты лучший) Я даже не знаю что бы я без тебя делал.