# Luminati добавить новый порт через ssh

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

После установки Luminati на Ubuntu 18.04 через доступ ssh, он просит настроить порты через браузер 127.0.0.1:22999, но у меня нет возможности запустить браузер на консоли. Есть ли другие методы, чтобы создать новые порты, которые будут слушать процесс?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/191416 ?

Comment: Да, это помогло, только нужно было вместо 127.0.0.1 свой внешний ип вписать. Спасибо за ответ, я даже и не знал, что так можно оказывается.