# прокси через ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Есть две vm под управлением ubuntu 20. Обе находятся в одной подсети, одном vlan. Одна имеет доступ в интернет другая нет. К обеим виртуалкам у меня рут доступ. Поднимаю ssh туннель к vm с интернетом: `ssh -N -D 9090 [USER]@[SERVER_IP]`. Как мне сделать, что бы все интернет соединения проходили через данный прокси?

Желательно что бы эти настройки обнулялись после перезагрузки.

Comment: Похожая тема: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/191416

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-бы от слова совсем, наверно никак. Можно использовать Environment variable

```
export http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:9090 https_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:9090
```

тогда большинство адекватного софта (которое использует соединения ОС) пойдёт по туннелю, но это не во всём софте работает. Можно жестко забить правила в proxy chains но при отвале туннеля на изолированной машине начнется то ещё веселье. А вообще лучший вариант, я такой использую на backup машинах. Это поднять реальный живой проксик, ограничить его в firewalld по полной программе (обновы, zabbix, и строго необходимые ресурсы), и тогда работать с реально живым прокси сервером.