# Как сделать VPN сервер из VPS?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, vps

У меня есть обычный VPS сервер на Ubuntu. Я хочу из него сделать VPN, то есть чтобы можно было в браузере указать VPN и им пользоваться. Единственное, что у этого сервера аж 30 IP адресов, мне нужно реализовать такую логику, что к какому IP мы подключаемся с такого и выходим в интернет.

Насколько мне подойдет **OpenVpn**?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/178576

Comment: в общем, непонятно, о чём вопрос: в теле вопроса упоминается vpn-сервер, в заголовке — прокси-сервер, а какой протокол[ы] через него надо проксировать — не укаказно. ещё и vps тут каким-то боком фигурирует. определитесь, пожалуйста, что именно вам нужно, и внесите правки в вопрос.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin соглашусь, исправил. Мне нравится Ваш ответ, но единственное у меня немного не стандартно, что IP несколько

Comment: не надо в корне менять всю суть вопроса, если на него уже были получены ответы. задайте лучше новый вопрос. при необходимости дайте ссылку на этот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если есть доступ к серверу по SSH, просто одной командой установите на клиентской машине [sshuttle](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle). Второй командой запустите его. И всё. Все соединения уже перенаправляются через VPS. Сам трафик шифрован SSH. Если вам надо скрываться от спецслужб, то вам нужен shadowsocks поверх какой-нибудь кастомной реализации [Snowflake](https://github.com/arlolra/snowflake) c маскировкой fingerprint как DNS-трафик. Последнее, кстати, реализуется [iodine](https://code.kryo.se/iodine/).

Answer (score 1):

Софт соответствущий поставить.
Вряд ли нужен полноценный прокси типа squid, скорее всего прокси нужен для обхода РКН. Если так, то у меня плохие новости - это не поможет. Потому что запрос до прокси конечно дойдет, но поскольку он открыт для аналитики, его запросто могут перехватить-заблокировать-подделать-и-еще-сделать-нехорошее
Для таких вещей нужен не (только) прокси (его конечно можно будет использовать), но и VPN, который обеспечит доставку запросов немодифицированными.

Comment: А как я могу настроить, чтобы конечный сервер, не мог понять что это VPN?

Comment: Вряд-ли это возможно, или же я не знаю как тогда можно это реализовать