# Как пользоваться IP-адресом друга?

Tags: python, http, сеть, сокет, ip

Мне нужно через IP-адрес своего друга зайти на какой-нибудь сайт, на своем компьютере. Какую программу/скрипт/команду должен запустить друг для этого? (Желательно чтоб это был какой-нибудь python скрипт).
В Гугле искал что-то, но нужного не нашел.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он нарушает тематику сайта

Comment: для разнообразия: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/178576

Answer (score 0):

почитай про shadowsocks, настраивается не сложно, будешь сидеть с его ip.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое решение TeamViewer, формально уд для пк. Просто разобраться, часто юзают для настроек пк удалённо. Однако используется именно для уд управления пк.

Comment: а что такое «уд для пк»? среди [предлагаемых википедией значений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%B4) подходящего не нашёл.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin удалённого управления, полагаю, имел ввиду автор

Comment: Алекс прав.

уд = удалённый доступ (удалённое управление)