# Не открывается в браузере Apache Nifi

Tags: ubuntu

Установила Apache Nifi на сервер Ubuntu 22.4, который стоит на виртуальной машине на сервере VK Cloud. Вот результат команды `sudo ./nifi.sh status`

```
2023-12-11 18:04:08,336 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Apache NiFi is currently running, listening to Bootstrap on port 43141, PID=4636.
```

Понимаю, что мне нужно пробросить порты с виртуальной машины на свою локальную, чтобы была возможность подключиться извне, но как это сделать?

Comment: Ну это надо смотреть в админке ВК Клауд дали ли тебе белый ip. Если нет - как вытаскивать по их мнению сервисы наружу. А вообще, про проброс можно тут почитать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/191416