# Armbian CLI не могу зайти на веб интерфейс модема huawei e3372

Tags: linux, администрирование, модемы, armbian-linux, huawei

есть такая проблема:
есть устройство на Armbian CLI, к нему подключен модем Huawei e3372 со статическим айпи адрессом и в нем прописаны DMZ с айпи адрессом устройства, я могу по этому айпи адрессу подключаться через SSH на устройство, так же я могу зайти на устройство через SSH в локальной сети. У меня возникла проблема в том, что мне нужно открыть веб-интерфейс модема, для того что бы увидеть смски или поменять файлы конфигурации на нем, каким образом я могу это сделать через коммандную строку?
P.S. в системе браузера никакого нет.

Comment: Используйте "устройство" в качестве socks proxy (ssh -D 3128 на него, затем на машине, с которой идёте, укажите браузеру в настройках прокси, что у вас SOCKS на порту 3128). Ну или можно попробовать lynx/links, запущенные на "устройстве".

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533542/191416 ?

Answer (score 1):

SSH -L 8800:192.168.0.1:80 user@ip

Потом в браузере переходи на http://127.0.0.1:8800